# Best way to hook a custom url?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, url-rewriting, urls, api

Let say I've a custom page with slug created "**/products**", I want user will be able to POST to a form with url  "**/products/create**" and allow us to render some JSON output.

The "**/products/create**" page does not actually exist.

I see from [1], the basic approach are

1. Add a rewrite if match my target url, add a custom query var, e.g. is_my_action=1
2. Register the custom query var (is_my_action) via "query_vars" action hook
3. In the parse_request hook check for this query var, and perform my works.

This approach work, but seems a little hackish, are there any potential issue with the above approach?

Are there any better way to add custom virtual url that  ?

[1] http://www.coderrr.com/create-an-api-endpoint-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 2):

The approach is pretty much sound, this is how these things work in WordPress.

You might want to use [`add_rewrite_enpoint()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint) for implementation though, since it compresses multiple steps into on integrated call and fits many use cases well.

Comment: updated link : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_endpoint/